# Choosing n numbers from a set and finding their sum

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have no idea where to start with this problem. I've been stuck on it for awhile any guidance would be appreciated.

$A = [2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32,35]$

This sets consists of all numbers in the form 3k+2 which are less than or equal to 35. What is the smallest number n that has the following property: if we choose n numbers from A randomly, then there will always be a pair of numbers that sum to 37.

Comment: Hint:  Consider the pairs that sum to $37$.  In a worst case, you choose one from each.

Comment: Hint: there are six pairs that sum to $37$. By [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), ...

Comment: Thank you for the hint. So I have divided the set into 6 pair sets that sum two 12. Applying pigeon hole principle to it guarantees that two of them are selected are from one of those 6 sets. Thus to guarantee this the smallest number of n should be 7 because you can choose {17,20,23,26,29,32,35}. Does this make sense?

Comment: That is correct.  You need to select $7$ numbers.